# Trouble getting data from an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I've got this array:

```
array(1) { 
   ["sensory-evaluation"]=> array(6) { 
     ["name"]=> string(18) "Sensory    Evaluation" 
     ["value"]=> string(43) "10/22/2015 at 6:00pm | 11/25/2015 at 6:00pm"
     ["position"]=> string(1) "3" 
     ["is_visible"]=> int(1) 
     ["is_variation"]=> int(1) 
     ["is_taxonomy"]=> int(0) 
    } 
}
```

I need to be able to get the data from `["value"]`. If I do `$arr["sensory-evaluation"]["value"]` I can get it but the problem is `["sensory-evaluation"]` will be different for each element in my array so I need a way to abstract that part but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: This question has a formatting issue. Will you please format your source code to be better readable?

Comment: Can you give an example of the array that's different from the example you gave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only one item in the array as you show then:

```
echo current($arr)['value'];
```

If you don't know if it exists:

```
if(isset(current($arr)['value'])) {
    echo current($arr)['value'];
}
```

You could also do:

```
echo array_values($arr)[0]['value'];
```

Answer (score 0):

why not use a for each

```
function getValue($arr){
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        var $subArray=$arr[$key];
       if( array_key_exists ('value' ,$subArray))
         return $arr[$key]['value'];
    }
}
```

Comment: That was close, but it was throwing an error. This seems to be working though.

`function getValue($arr){
     foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        if( array_key_exists ($key ,$arr ))
          return $arr[$key]['value'];
     }
 }`

Comment: you can try that just extracted the first array to a variable

Comment: Please edit your answer and change it.  Then delete the comment.

Comment: Im sorry i dont understand the comment what do u mean Rohit